# How to exclude data if any record is not matching in any of the column in the another Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Table A and Table  B

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableA]
(
    [ID] Int NULL,
    [sk] bigint NULL,
    [class] int NULL,
    [Values] int NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableA] ([ID], [sk], [class], [Values])
VALUES (1, 17734, 5, 66443), (2, 17734, 4, 5456), 
       (3, 17734, 6, 445645), (4, 17734, 7, 4534),
       (5, 16601, 4, 5443), (6, 16601, 7, 453434), 
       (7, 16601, 8, 76645), (8, 16601, 5, 9875)


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableB]
(
    [ID] Int NULL,
    [sk] bigint NULL,
    [class] int NULL,
    [Values] int NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableB] ([ID], [sk], [class], [Values])
VALUES (1, 17734, 5, 66443), (2, 17734, 4, 5456),
       (3, 17734, 6, 445645), (4, 17734, 7, 4534),
       (5, 16601, 4, 5443), (6, 16601, 7, 453434),
       (7, 16601, 8, 76645), (8, 16601, 5, 9875)
```

I'm looking to join both the  tables  with all columns in each table. If any record is  not  matching then we need  to remove all the SK.

For 17734 value all the columns from the both tables  are matching  then I need  to get the values  for 17734 .

For 16601 value only 1 value is not matching so I don't want to bring all the values for 16601.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    DC.[sk], 
    DC.class,
    DC.Values,
    DB.class AS DCC,
    DB.Values AS DBC
FROM
    [dbo].[TableA]
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[TableA] DB ON DC.[sk] = DB.[sk] 
                      AND DC.class = DB.class
                      AND DC.Values = DB.Values;
```

After joining, I get:

```
 sk   class Values  class values
--------------------------------
16601   3   65567   NULL NULL
16601   4   5443    4   5443
16601   7   453434  7   453434
16601   8   76645   8   76645
17734   4   5456    4   5456
17734   5   66443   5   66443
17734   6   445645  6   445645
17734   7   4534    7   4534
```

Output :

```
 sk   class Values  class values
 --------------------------------
17734   4   5456    4   5456
17734   5   66443   5   66443
17734   6   445645  6   445645
17734   7   4534    7   4534
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must do the whole join to discover if some of the results should be removed. To reuse the query results, use a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and refer to it twice - once for the results and again to filter out the unwanted rows:

```sql
with table1 as (
    select distinct 
        DC.sk, 
        DC.class,
        DC.Values,
        DB.class AS DCC,
        DB.Values AS DBC
    from dbo.TableA
    left join dbo.TableB DB on DC.sk = DB.sk 
        and DC.class = DB.class
        and DC.Values = DB.Values
)
select *
from table1
where sk not in (select sk from table1 where DCC is null)
```

---

BTW, you have a bug in your query: You're joining `[dbo].[TableA]` with itself, but it should be joined to `[dbo].[TableB]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **EXCEPT** operator to get your expected result. I will explain my query in step by step process.

**Step 1**: I am finding out non-matching rows using **Except** operator:-

```
    SELECT A.sk, A.class, A.[Values] FROM TableA A

    EXCEPT

    SELECT B.sk, B.class, B.[Values] FROM TableB B
```

**Step 2**: Now I am selecting the **sk** of non-matching rows using:-

```
 SELECT T.sk FROM (query of step 1)T
```

Step 3: I am excluding those sk from TableA using:-

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
WHERE sk NOT IN(query of step 2)
```

So our final Query is look like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM TableA
 WHERE sk NOT IN
 (
     SELECT T.sk FROM 
     (
        SELECT A.sk, A.class, A.[Values] FROM TableA A

        EXCEPT

        SELECT B.sk, B.class, B.[Values] FROM TableB B
     )T
 )
```